# File Downloaded as ASCII text in Python

Tags: python, download, package

I have written this code to download a package file. However, although I am able to download the data, the file type is being recognized as ASCII text and binary data is there. When I download the data via Chrome, the file is downloaded as a zip file containing multiple RPMs. I have ensured that all parameters in the headers and payload are consistent with those obtained via Chrome inspect. However, I am not sure what is wrong or missing in the code. Please assist.

Note:- package download based on the payload info. Different payload for different O/S.

```
[***** ~]# file linux-client-bundle.ext
linux-client-bundle.ext: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators

 url = "abc.com/plugin/products/client-management/v2/downloads/download"  
api_token = 'token-1234'  
headers = {
    'session': api_token,  
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',  
}

# Define the payload (JSON data)
payload = {
    "category_file": {
        "category": "CATEGORY_LINUX",
        "file_type": "FILE_TYPE_BUNDLE"
    }
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False, json=payload, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("First few bytes of binary data:", response.content[:10])
    with open("linux-client-bundle.ext", "wb") as fd:
       for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
         fd.write(chunk)
    print("File downloaded successfully as:")
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code)
```

Comment: It seems like the code you've written should indeed download the file as binary data if it's being sent as such by the server. The `wb` mode in the open function ensures that the file is written in binary mode, which is correct for a ZIP file containing RPMs.

Comment: Thanks for your time. May I know, how can I convert this binary data further to get the original data.

Comment: First, are you sure that there *is* a problem? There is no certain way of identifying the type of a file on a Unix system — the `file` utility just looks at the data and makes an educated guess. Having said that, if the data is supposed to be a ZIP file, it seems unlikely that it would be mistaken for ASCII text. If you are sure that there is a problem, then I would recommend having a look at the actual data you got. Is it possible that you got an error page, for example? Unlikely with a 200 status code, but... What does the Content-Type header in the response say?

Comment: Content-Type: application/json. Same verified via chrome inspect.  However, I used same parameters which chrome inspect provided and there file download as zip file and have multiple RPM inside zip file. In my case python downloaded file of same size but have only binary data. So not sure if I am missing anything in code or what else I can do to fix this.

Comment: Just incase inspect data can highlight something. authority:
abc
:method:
POST
:path:
/plugin/products/client-management/v2/downloads/download
:scheme:
https
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language:
en-US,en;q=0.9
Content-Length:
78
Content-Type:
application/json
Origin:
Sec-Fetch-Site:
same-origin
Session:
asdfUser-Agent:
X-Request-Id:
asdf
Payload details :- {"category_file":{"category":"CATEGORY_LINUX","file_type":"FILE_TYPE_BUNDLE"}}

Comment: Finally, I got solution for this. here is the line of code added.   data = response.json()
content = data.get('content', '')
decoded_content = base64.b64decode(content)
with open("downloaded_file.zip", "wb") as file:
      file.write(decoded_content)

print("File downloaded successfully.")

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import base64


# Define the URL of the file to download
url = "abc"

api_token = ''


headers = {
    'session': api_token,
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
}

# Define the payload (JSON data)
payload = {
    "category_file": {
        "category": "CATEGORY_LINUX",
        "file_type": "FILE_TYPE_BUNDLE"
    }
}

# Send a GET request with the payload to download the file
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False, json=payload, stream=True)
#content_type = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
data = response.json()
content = data.get('content', '')
decoded_content = base64.b64decode(content)
with open("downloaded_file.zip", "wb") as file:
      file.write(decoded_content)

print("File downloaded successfully.")
```